# event for check box in jtable header

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtable, jtableheader

hi i have a jtable with checkbox in column and column header

problem is if i click on the first column header,
the first column header is select and the the second one

```
    String[] columnNames = {"Am", "Pm", "Integer", "String"};
    Object[][] data = {{true, true, 1, "BBB"}, {false, true, 12, "AAA"},
        {true, false, 2, "DDD"}, {false, false, 5, "CCC"},
        {true, true, 3, "EEE"}, {false, false, 6, "GGG"},
        {true, true, 4, "FFF"}, {false, false, 7, "HHH"}};
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }
    };
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setHeaderRenderer(
            new HeaderRenderer2(table.getTableHeader()));


    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setHeaderRenderer(
            new HeaderRenderer2(table.getTableHeader()));
```

i created a table cell renderer

```
public class HeaderRenderer2 implements TableCellRenderer {

private final JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox();

public HeaderRenderer2(JTableHeader header) {
    check.setOpaque(false);
    check.setFont(header.getFont());
    header.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            JTable table = ((JTableHeader) e.getSource()).getTable();
            TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
            int viewColumn = columnModel.getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
            int modelColumn = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(viewColumn);
            if (modelColumn == 0) {
                check.setSelected(!check.isSelected());
                TableModel m = table.getModel();
                Boolean f = check.isSelected();
                for (int i = 0; i < m.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    m.setValueAt(f, i, 0);
                }
                ((JTableHeader) e.getSource()).repaint();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable tbl, Object val, boolean isS, boolean hasF, int row, int col) {
    TableCellRenderer r = tbl.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
    JLabel l = (JLabel) r.getTableCellRendererComponent(tbl, val, isS, hasF, row, col);
    l.setIcon(new CheckBoxIcon(check));
    return l;
}

private static class CheckBoxIcon implements Icon {

    private final JCheckBox check;

    public CheckBoxIcon(JCheckBox check) {
        this.check = check;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        return check.getPreferredSize().width;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
        return check.getPreferredSize().height;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        SwingUtilities.paintComponent(
                g, check, (Container) c, x, y, getIconWidth(), getIconHeight());
    }
}
}
```

image at the top nothing selected[image: problem displayed]
image at the bottom after a click on the column header (AM)

getTableCellRendererComponent happen before the mouseClicked event so i'm not able to get the clicked column

any idea?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the mouse listener.  Both instances are listing for mouse clicks on the header that have a column ==0.  Therefore both get checked or unchecked when you click on that header.

Comment: You will have to tell the class which column to check in the constructor.  Or have it found out which column it is the renderer for.  Or better pull the "checked value storage" out into another class that acts as a model just like your table model does.

Comment: before i ask on the forum, i was tried the first solution but that was not working... i dont' watched the correct column for setValueAt method

i don't know if your second solution is possible

sad there are few information about good pratice with swing

Comment: @user660503 and I tried your code in form that posted, JCheckBox missed CellRenderer, jzd +1

Answer (score 3):

You should pass your column index in the set value loop

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
             JTable table = ((JTableHeader) e.getSource()).getTable();
             TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
             int viewColumn = columnModel.getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
             int modelColumn = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(viewColumn);
             if (modelColumn == 0 || modelColumn == 1) {
                 check.setSelected(!check.isSelected());
                 TableModel m = table.getModel();
                 Boolean f = check.isSelected();
                 for (int i = 0; i < m.getRowCount(); i++) {
                     m.setValueAt(f, i, modelColumn);
                 }
                 ((JTableHeader) e.getSource()).repaint();
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

you mus indicate the column to modify

```
String[] columnNames = {"Am", "Pm", "Integer", "String"};
Object[][] data = {{true, true, 1, "BBB"}, {false, true, 12, "AAA"},
    {true, false, 2, "DDD"}, {false, false, 5, "CCC"},
    {true, true, 3, "EEE"}, {false, false, 6, "GGG"},
    {true, true, 4, "FFF"}, {false, false, 7, "HHH"}};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
    }
};
JTable table = new JTable(model);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setHeaderRenderer(
        new HeaderRenderer2(table.getTableHeader(), 0));


table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setHeaderRenderer(
        new HeaderRenderer2(table.getTableHeader(), 1));
```

and

```
public HeaderRenderer2(JTableHeader header, final int index) {

    // index is the column to be modified

    check.setOpaque(false);
    check.setFont(header.getFont());
    header.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            JTable table = ((JTableHeader) e.getSource()).getTable();
            TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
            int viewColumn = columnModel.getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
            int modelColumn = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(viewColumn);
            if (modelColumn == index) {
                check.setSelected(!check.isSelected());
                TableModel m = table.getModel();
                Boolean f = check.isSelected();
                for (int i = 0; i < m.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    m.setValueAt(f, i, index);
                }
                ((JTableHeader) e.getSource()).repaint();
            }else return;
        } 
    }
            );
}
```